# Why does it require quotes around my column names?

Tags: sql, postgresql, api, rest, go

Using the module github.com/lib/pq module to handle postgres database connection and commands while running on macos.

JSON file (post.json):

```json
{
    "Title":"thistitle",
    "Desc":"thisdesc",
    "Content":"thiscontent",
    "PageNum":123
}
```

Golang REST API function:

```golang
func (server *Server) createNewArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var article &Article
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&article)
    _, err = server.Database.Exec(`INSERT INTO articles ("title", "desc", "content", "pagenum") values ($1, $2, $3, $4)`, article.Title, article.Desc, article.Content, article.PageNum)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}
```

```sh
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @post.json http://<IP>:<PORT>/<ENDPOINT>
```

Inside the go function to execute the SQL command, pq complains unless I put quotations around the column names inside the command (... articles ("title", ...) ) and will not insert into the database followed by the error `pq: syntax error at or near "desc"` . In a normal SQL command, those quotations are not necessary.

I have seen examples online using unquoted column names.

Why is it then necessary for my code to require these extra quotations? Is it part of pq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DESC` is a [reserved PostgreSQL keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-keywords-appendix.html). As per the linked document:

> Labeled “reserved” are those tokens that are not allowed as column or table names

and

> As a general rule, if you get spurious parser errors for commands that contain any of the listed key words as an identifier you should try to quote the identifier to see if the problem goes away.

You only need to put quotes around `DESC` because it's a reserved keyword - this is an error from PostgreSQL and will occur however you run the query (see this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eceMfuw5k7wr4rE5bPjutD/0)).